# Non Atomic Parallel Reduction with Metal

Tags: parallel-processing, gpgpu, metal

I'm just getting into the world of parallel reductions. I'm trying to implement this with Metal. I have been able to successfully write a simple version using atomic types and using the atomic_fetch_* functions.

I am now trying trying to do something similar with non-atomic variables, a simple struct.

Defined like this:

```
struct Point2
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

With a kernel function like this:

```
kernel void compareX(const device Point2 *array [[ buffer(0) ]],
                 device Point2 *result [[ buffer(1) ]],
                 uint id [[ thread_position_in_grid ]],
                 uint tid [[ thread_index_in_threadgroup ]],
                 uint bid [[ threadgroup_position_in_grid ]],
                 uint blockDim [[ threads_per_threadgroup ]]) {

    threadgroup Point2 shared_memory[THREADGROUP_SIZE];

    uint i = bid * blockDim + tid;
    shared_memory[tid] = array[i];

    threadgroup_barrier(mem_flags::mem_threadgroup);

    // reduction in shared memory
    for (uint s = 1; s < blockDim; s *= 2) {
        if (tid % (2 * s) == 0 && shared_memory[tid + s].x < shared_memory[tid].x) {

            shared_memory[tid] = shared_memory[tid + s];
        }
        threadgroup_barrier(mem_flags::mem_threadgroup);
    }

    if (0 == tid ) {
///THIS IS NOT CORRECT
        result[0] = shared_memory[0];
    }

}
```

I first thought something was going wrong with the memory copying to/from the buffers but I have verified the to/from CPU/GPU is working correctly with the struct. I then realized it has to do with cross thread group synchronizations.

There are a lot of examples/doc for CUDA but very little for anything else and CUDA doesn't always translate very well to Metal.

What is the way to get cross thread group synchronization without atomic types?

The kernel is attempting to get the min Point in the input array. Right now the result changes across executions because of the write orders.

Comment: This is not using a compute kernel so it is not exactly the same as what you want to do, but if you want to have a look at a fragment shader based approach that implements a prefix sum in metal, here is a link: https://github.com/mdejong/MetalPrefixSum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the most correct, or best solution. But it is one I came up with after struggling with this for a while. If others find a better solution please post! This also may go out of date with different versions of Metal.

I first tried to use the `_atomic<T>` that is included in the Metal language on my struct. This *should* work. After struggling a ton with that I finally checked the doc and realized that template is currently restricted by apple to bool's, int's and uint's.

I then tried to use an atomic int to "lock" critical compare sections but wasn't successful in actually protecting the critical section. I was likely doing something wrong with this implementation and could see it working.

I then simplified to return an index instead of the point, which allows me to use an atomic_int on the result again. Kinda cheating, and still uses an atomic for the reduction. **But** it works so I can keep going.

Here is how the kernel now looks:

```
kernel void compareX(const device Point2 *array [[ buffer(0) ]],
                     device atomic_int *result [[ buffer(1) ]],
                     uint id [[ thread_position_in_grid ]],
                     uint tid [[ thread_index_in_threadgroup ]],
                     uint bid [[ threadgroup_position_in_grid ]],
                     uint blockDim [[ threads_per_threadgroup ]]) {

    threadgroup int shared_memory[THREADGROUP_SIZE];
    uint i = bid * blockDim + tid;
    shared_memory[tid] = i;

    threadgroup_barrier(mem_flags::mem_threadgroup);

    for (uint s = 1; s < blockDim; s *= 2) {
        if (tid % (2 * s) == 0) {
            // aggregate the index to our smallest value in shared_memory
            if ( array[shared_memory[tid + s]].x < array[shared_memory[tid]].x) {
                shared_memory[tid] = shared_memory[tid + s];
            }
        }
        threadgroup_barrier(mem_flags::mem_threadgroup);
    }
    if (0 == tid ) {
        // get the current index so we can test against that
        int current = atomic_load_explicit(result, memory_order_relaxed);

        if( array[shared_memory[0]].x < array[current].x) {
            while(!atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(result, &current, shared_memory[0], memory_order_relaxed, memory_order_relaxed)) {
                // another thread won. Check if we still need to set it.
                if (array[shared_memory[0]].x > array[current].x) {
                    // they won, and have a smaller value, ignore our best result
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```